# How to convert Unix time to time.Time in golang?

Tags: go

I want to covert Unix time (1494505756) to UTC format
just

```
import "time"
timeNow := time.Now()
```

I want to restore timeNow to UTC format. How to do that?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can get UTC and unix from time interface itself.

To convert unix timestamp to time object.
Use this:

```
t := time.Unix(1494505756, 0)
fmt.Println(t)
```

> **func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time**
>
> Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC. It is valid to pass nsec outside the range [0, 999999999]. Not all sec values have a corresponding time value. One such value is 1<<63-1 (the largest int64 value).

For UTC:

```
time.Now().UTC()
```

> UTC returns t with the location set to UTC.
>   Link: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#UTC

For Unix:

```
time.Now().Unix()
```

> Unix returns t as a Unix time, the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 UTC.
>   Link: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix

Comment: When creating a time from an epoch, is it common to want the timezone converted? I would have thought it more common to want it left in UTC.